# Inequality with assumptions not simplifying

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Can someone explain to me why the following does not simplify to `True` (as all constituents are positive)?

```
FullSimplify[a+b/(c+(d-e)^2)>0,Assumptions->And@@Thread[{a,b,c,d,e}>0]]
```

Most special cases including `e=0` or `a=b`,... do simplify correctly.

What I eventually want to do is to simplify expressions of the kind

```
Abs[a+b/(c+(d-e)^2)],
```

which should evaluate to `a+b/(c+(d-e)^2)` under given assumptions.

Any workarounds?

**Edit**
What I ended up doing for larger expressions was this:

```
expr[Abs[a+b/(c+(d-e)^2)]]/.Abs[x_]/;Simplify@Reduce[$Assumptions&&x>0]:>x
```

It's not particularly pretty, but it works. Thanks to ssch for the idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One workaround is to use Reduce instead, and simplify that with FullSimplify:

```
assum=And @@ Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} > 0];
Reduce[assum && a + b/(c + (d - e)^2) > 0]
(* Out: e > 0 && d > 0 && c > 0 && b > 0 && a > 0 *)
FullSimplify[%, assum]
(* Out: True *)
```

Comment: Good idea! Should have thought of that...

Comment: I just realized that this actually doesn't help me. What I would like is Mathematica to simplify Abs[a + b/(c + (d - e)^2)] for given assumptions.

Answer (score 11):

Either of the below logical formulations will handle this. Generic simplifiers might or might not react well to logical expressions.

```
In[21]:= Resolve[
 ForAll[{a, b, c, d, e}, 
  Implies[And @@ Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} > 0], 
   a + b/(c + (d - e)^2) > 0]]]

Out[21]= True

In[20]:= Resolve[
 ForAll[{a, b, c, d, e}, And @@ Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} > 0], 
  a + b/(c + (d - e)^2) > 0]]

Out[20]= True
```

Comment: That's very interesting to know! I didn't even know `Resolve` existed. But is there also a way to simplify `Abs[...]`? Of course I could do a replacement and apply your trick (or ssch's) but that's not very elegant.

Comment: Might be a straightforward way but none is coming to mind right now.