# Exponential function not simplified by FullSimplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to understand why the first expression doesn't simplify while the second does:

```
FullSimplify[a^q <= 1, {0 < a < 1, q > 0}]
FullSimplify[q Log[a] <= 0, {0 < a < 1, q > 0}]
```

Aren't these expressions equivalent under the supplied assumptions?

Comment: Whether the second form is simpler than the first is more like a matter of opinion I'm afraid. I see no reason why Simplify would make any changes in the first place...

Comment: @Gert I'm not claiming the second function as written is simpler, but both should evaluate to "True" because they are both always satisfied. The second does, but the first remains what it is..

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8093/inequality-with-assumptions-not-simplifying) workaround with `Reduce` instead. Not super pretty, but at least it shows that the algebra is correct. Applied to this example,

```
assum = {0 < a < 1, q > 0};
FullSimplify[Reduce[And@@ assum && a^q <= 1], assum]
```

I will wait a bit before accepting this answer in case anyone else has a more elegant approach, but didn't want you to go through the pain of typing out something that already has an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Or manually apply `Log`: `a^q <= 1 // ApplySides[Log, #] & // 
 FullSimplify[#, {0 < a < 1, q > 0}] &`